# Adding Web Part document library to my site using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I want to add my document library as a web part to my collection site.

[image]

how is that possible using PowerShell, please ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** it's possible to add a web part to a page using [PnP PowerShel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)

**Example**

```
Add-SPOWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/Pages/PnPPage.aspx" -Path "D:\PnP\NewWebPart.dwp" -ZoneId "WebPartZone2" -ZoneIndex 0
```

> **Note:** you can get the `.dwp` file by exporting the web part manually, **but** the document library doesn't have the export option, so try to export it as mentioned at [Unable to find the export web part option](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/unable-to-find-the-export-web-part-option)

Check the details steps,

- [Adding Web Parts To SharePoint Pages Using Pnp Powershell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-web-parts-to-sharepoint-pages-using-pnp-powershell/)
- [Adding Web Part To A SharePoint Online Page Using PnP Core CSOM Library](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-web-part-to-a-sharepoint-online-page-using-pnp-core-csom-library/)
- [Webpart Provisioning to SharePoint online by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Webpart-Provisioning-to-8171cfbf)

---

> If you are looking for adding a web part to web part gallery, check
>   [Deploy pre-configured web parts to web part gallery](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.UploadWebPart)