# SharePoint Online Web part Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I am trying to add two lists in a web part page along with a HTML form web part list app part to pages that are on the same sites. In order to access list from another site, I have to add one of the list in page viewer web part. However with page viewer web part I am not able to make a web part connection between HTML form Web part and list web part. Does anyone know how can we add a list web part from another subsite and make a connection with other web parts on the same page?

Comment: Have a look at this article **[Show List From Parent Site In Sub Site](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)** to show a list from another subsite and check if you can perform your connection or not!

Comment: Are you using modern or classic SharePoint?

Comment: I am using classic web part page

Comment: @Mohamed,  I tried to follow the instructions. I did not find 'Edit in Advance Mode option' after checking out the page so I edited in normal mode in SharePoint Designer. And save webpart to the Site Gallery as per the instructions. But When I pick webpart from Miscellaneous category I get an error "The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web Part description file (*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains well-formed XML.."

Answer (score 0):

1.Export the web part from the source site.

Reference:

[Export web part to another site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4d2d2084-e7ad-4573-b3e1-23de6636829a/export-web-part-to-another-site?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

[Unable to find the export web part option](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/unable-to-find-the-export-web-part-option/220671)

2.Import the web part into subsite.

[image]